# Select added item by default and close list

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, dropdown

I'm using Kendo UI for jQuery and I'm using a Dropdowlist to display list of option with values that I get from my database but also, I want to add a function to create an option if this is not on the list. At the moment I'm able to do it but I'm facing some issues:

1. The new item is not selected by default after it's created.
2. The dropdown list doesn't seem to be closed. Stays open it and just showing the option I just create.

This is the code I'm using:

```
$(function() {
            
    $("#dropDownList-addNewItem").kendoDropDownList({
        dataSource: dataFromDB,
        dataTextField: "name",
        dataValueField: "id",
        filter: "contains",
        noDataTemplate: $("#noDataTemplate-addItem").html()
    })
            
});
        
function addItem(widgetId, newName) {
    var widget = $("#" + widgetId).data("kendoDropDownList");
    var dataSource = widget.dataSource;
    
    dataSource.add({
        id: 0,
        name: newName,
    });

    dataSource.one("sync", function() {
        // I think this is the problem
        widget.select(dataSource.view().length - 1);
            
     });

     dataSource.sync();
}
```

**NOTE**: I cannot add a valid ID to the datasource, because my backend is checking for a id  greater than 0 to execute an update instead of an insert.

Answer (score 0):

What's the dataSource definition? The Kendo Demos website has this exact [example](https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/dropdownlist/addnewitem), though the dataSource has a create endpoint defined. It should return the newly added item, with it's actual ID.

If the item is added successfully and you see a popup with only the new item - this is happening as the filter of the DropDownList is preserved and the actual item you have filtered for now exists and is selected. You can use the [close](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/dropdownlist/methods/close) method to close the popup:

```
 dataSource.one("sync", function() {
      widget.select(dataSource.view().length - 1);
      widget.close();
    });
```